# How to replace special characters in file name with Underscore symbol using Unix?

Tags: python, unix

I am working upon the task, where I need to replace the Special characters in the file name with _, in all the recursive folders in unix/Python.

PFB the Unix code.

```
#!/bin/sh
 # Shell script to find out all the files under a directory and
 #its subdirectories. This also takes into consideration those files
 #or directories which have spaces or newlines in their names

DIR="."

function list_files()
{
 if !(test -d "$1")
 then echo $1; return;
fi

function rename_files()
{
    str="$1"

    regex="[0-9a-zA-Z]._+"
    if [[ ! "$str" =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$ ]]
    then
       echo $1
    else
       echo "f you"
    fi
}

cd "$1"
# echo; echo `pwd`:; #Display Directory name

 for i in *
 do
 if test -d "$i" #if dictionary
 then
 list_files "$i" #recursively list files
cd ..
 else
 # echo "$i"; #Display File name
 rename_files "$i"
fi

 done
}
```

Can someone help me with the code to replace the characters in the file name with _?

Eg., If file name is ABC$XYZ*PQR.xls, it should be renamed as ABC_XYZ_PQR.xls.

This process has to be done for all the files in folders and its sub folder.

Please help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding, translation, or tutorial service.  Post *your* Python code per the posting guidelines, and we can help repair a localized error.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: Sure I will add Python Code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a bracket subexpression of a regular expression, the caret ("`^`") acts as a negation, i.e. *not* the characters in the brackets. For example, whereas

```sh
echo 'ABC$XYZ*PQR.xls' | sed 's/[0-9a-zA-Z._]/_/g'
```

would yield "`___$___*_______`", the following code,

```sh
echo 'ABC$XYZ*PQR.xls' | sed 's/[^0-9a-zA-Z._]/_/g'
```

would yield "`ABC_XYZ_PQR.xls`". You could modify the latter code for use in your `rename_files()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
:>echo 'ABC$XYZ*PQR.xls' | sed 's#[^[:alnum:]|\.]#_#g' 
ABC_XYZ_PQR.xls
:>
```